# What is the testability problems of window in javascripts which is solved in $windows in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, testing

As a novice start to learn angular js and with a weak javascript background, could someone give some more illustrative examples and explain further what is the idea/purpose behind the $window, a built-in service in AngularJS?

what is the below mentioned global problem for testing?
Thanks

Reading a book "AngularJS up and running", but do not understand its explanation:

> The $window service in AngularJS is nothing but a wrapper around the global window object. The sole reason for its existence is to ***avoid global state, especially in tests.*** Instead of directly working with the window object, we can ask for and work with $window. In the unit tests, the $window service can be easily ***mocked out*** (available for free with the AngularJS mocking library).

and then visit official documentation of AngularJS:
https://docs.angularjs.org/API/ng/service/$window

> A reference to the browser's window object. While the window is globally available in JavaScript, it causes ***testability problems, because it is a global variable.*** In AngularJS we always refer to it through the $window service, so it may be ***overridden, removed or mocked for testing.***

Mark bold and italic for the concepts/words that I do not understand.

Comment: DI, you can mock `$window`, but u cant mock `window`

Comment: Sorry, I think I do not understand about the concept of "mock"/"mock out" as well? What do you mean mock $window? Simulating and create an separated individual instance out of the blueprint of window?